# Adding a status code to a :root redirect in Rails 3 causes annoying "You are being redirected" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This code is being executed in a `rescue_from`.

#### This works:

```
redirect_to :root, :notice => 'Mice'
```

#### This causes a Rails 3 to generate a "You are being redirected" page:

```
redirect_to :root, :status => 403, :notice => 'Mice'
```

There have been similar questions, but I haven't seen anything recent or quite matching this scenario. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're seeing this page because of the behavior of the browser. A 403 tells the browser that the request is completed with the status "Forbidden". You need to send a 3xx series status code to do a redirect. Using `redirect_to` without an explicit code sends a 302.

Note that if you use curl to test your second example you'll see the "You are being redirected" page for both a 302 and a 403 status code. `redirect_to` sends that back in the response regardless, but it's the browser that determines how to handle the request.

Comment: Nice Answer. But for me it still doesn't work. I redirect like this "redirect_to "/signin", :status => 301" and I am still getting the annoying "you are being redirected" in the browser and a "406 Not Acceptable" in my console. I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertReiz your best bet is to open another question and include the relevant controller action and failing spec.